# QGIS projected coords vs lat/longs in coordinate capture

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

My project CRS is 23031 (ED50,UTM 31N).
Lat long coords displayed in Coordinate Capture are WGS84. How can I get ED50 lat longs when using coordinate capture? Is there a GUI coordinate transform utility that will go back and forwards between projected coords and lat longs in my choice of datum or spheroid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second box shows the coordinates in the CRS of the project.

But you can also click on the button to the left of the first box to change the CRS that is displayed. It defaults to WGS84, but you can choose any CRS.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is ridiculously easy! I'm embarrassed now that I didn't discover that for myself.

Comment: @DaveRichards No problem, easy once you know. But if the answer is correct can you accept it. Just click on the green check mark next to this answer. It helps keep StackExchange organised.